# Xamarin Shell use Contentview inside ShellContent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have the following code in my AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell ....
...
    <TabBar Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="Green" Shell.BackgroundColor="Gray" Shell.NavBarHasShadow="True" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
        <ShellContent Title="WebView" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="LoginView" >
            <local:LoginPage/>
        </ShellContent>

            <ShellContent Title="Listing" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="ListingView"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ListingView}" />

...
```

Where LoginPage is / has to be a `ContentView`, because I need to display other Views inside of it.

But I can't figure out how to use a `ContentView` as `ShellContent` because every time i get a    `specified cast is not valid`-exception. Is there any other way to use a `ContentView` inside `ShellContent`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At least in the example it's used like: `<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" Route="LoginPage" />`

Comment: Yeah but there I also get the same exception

Comment: Can't you use a `ContentPage` ?

Comment: Long story but no, unfortunately I cant. It needs to be ```ContentView``` I could extend my question if that would help?

Comment: I don't think that extending your question about that would help. :/

Comment: How about wrapping your LoginView with a "LoginPage", which is a `ContentPage`, and put into ShellContent,

Answer (score 0):

A [ShellContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/#pages) object represents the `ContentPage` object for each `FlyoutItem` or `Tab`.

We can't set a `ContentView` inside ShellContent .

The only way is to place the `LoginView` into a ContentPage , and then use in `ShellContent`.